# Как реализовать несколько методов функционального интерфейса через лямбда выражения?

Tags: java, интерфейс, лямбда-выражение

Доброго времени суток!

Есть такой рабочий код. Но если я добавляю в интерфейс `SomeFunction<T>` после метода  `T func(T v)`  второй метод под названием `T func2(T v)`, то естественно система запросит реализовать второй метод интерфейса в классе Main. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как реализовать с помощью лямбда выражений второй метод по точному подобию с первым методом. Допустим первый метод возвращает  конкатенируемые строки (я его уже реализовал), а второй метод пускай возвращает сумму двух чисел. Как это сделать?

```
interface SomeFunction<T>{
    T func(T v);
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SomeFunction factorial = (v)-> { String b = "Hello" + v; return  b; };

        System.out.println( factorial.func(" World"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) `FunctionalInterface` сказано:

> Conceptually, a functional interface has exactly one abstract method.

Как по-вашему будет выбираться метод, используемый в качестве лямбда выражения из вашего интерфейса, если их будет 2? Нужно делать отдельный интерфейс для другой операции.

Но, даже в случае если у вас будет 2 метода `T func1(T v)` и `T func2(T v)`, то по сути это ведь одно и то же, это лишь **интерфейс**. Реализация лежит на вас, внутри лямбда-выражения.
То есть как вы написали

```
SomeFunction factorial = (v) -> {
        String b="Hello"+v; return  b;
    };
```

вы аналогично ниже можете написать

```
SomeFunction<Integer> sum = (v) -> {
        int a = 0 + v; return  a;
    };
```

Comment: Цель была в том, чтобы вывести одновременно два результата, один результат, который по одному методу рассчитывается, а второй результат по другому.

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan написать две лямбды и вызвать подряд, нет?

Comment: Я Вас услышал и понял вроде, но теперь возникает вопрос зачем тогда разные функциональные интерфейсы нужны, если можно просто реализацию поменять? Дело просто в количестве параметров передоваемых?

Comment: Так никто не ответил, дело в количестве передоваемых параметров? Поэтому под разные цели разные функциональные интерфейсы нужны?

Comment: @VaagnAkopyan аргументы, их типы, возвращаемый тип, выкидываемые исключения - в каждом может быть что-то своё